# Confused about Javascript Constructor and Prototype

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to build a custom constructor to be used and I'm a little confused about the prototype part. I'm testing it and when I go to do a console.log(testVar.getHostname); it returns function as text.

So I have the following.

```
function nodeInfo(hostname) {
    this.hostname = hostname;
};

nodeInfo.prototype.getHostname = function() {
    return this.hostname;
};

var testVar = new nodeInfo("google.com");

console.log(testVar.getHostname);
```

Output is the following.

```
function () {
return this.hostname;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Can the prototype method be outside of the constructor? I've seen it done that way on a bunch of articles from searching google.
Such as http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's correct.  `testVar.getHostname` is a function.  Have you tried calling it?  `console.log(testVar.getHostname());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `console.log(testVar.getHostName())` to run the function.

Functions in JavaScript are first-class values. They can be referenced by variables, stored in an array, set as properties, etc. In this case you're asking it to print a string value for the function, which happens to be the source code in this case. You could also do:

```
console.log( typeof testVar.getHostName );
// "function"
```

To level up your knowledge, examine and ponder the output of the following:

```
var testVar = new nodeInfo("google.com");
hostName = "Global";
var f1 = testVar.getHostName;
var o = { f2: testVar.getHostName, hostName:"In Object" };

console.log( testVar.getHostName() );
console.log( f1() );
console.log( o.f2() );
f1.call( o );
o.f2.call( testVar );
```